# User mode access to the TPM on Windows

Tags: windows, registry, acl, privileges, tpm

I have developed a windows application which among other things accesses the TPM's NVM.
During the development, I tested it by running as Administrator and everything works great.
The problem is, I don't want it to run as Administrator when it will be released and used by the project.

I've thought about elevating the application's privileges for a limited period of time, but this requires the Admin account to assign the user account with rights that he shouldn't have.

Then I came across with this document:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/tbs/using-tbs which states that one can modify the access restrictions by creating a registry value, what it doesn't say is how.

1. Which way is better to reach the above goal?
2. If it's by elevating privileges then which one(s) is it? and why it is better?
3. If it's by using the above document's method, then how can I modify the access restrictions and how?

Answer (score 1):

For TPM 2, on Windows 8 and up, you will have to add the specific command you want to use to the list of [allowed commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/tbs/command-blocking) by its ordinal.

The registry location is:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE    
   Software
      Microsoft
         Tpm
            AllowedW8Commands
               List
```

For example, if you wanted to allow the NV Read command, you would add a new `REG_DWORD` registry entry with the name "14E", as that is the hex code for the `TPM2_CC_NV_READ` ordinal, and the value of "1".

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried that as well, Microsoft documentation states that it should be under:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\
   Software\
      Microsoft\
         Tpm\
            AllowedW8Commands\
               List`
Well, I tried both (with or without List) and still no access to the non-volatile memory, and I believe I added all the commands I used and maybe more.
What am I missing?

Comment: Yeah it is with `List`, sorry about that. What is your Windows version and the TPM version? Also, can you share the piece of code you're trying to execute?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share the code, but what I'm actually doing is writing and reading from the TPM's NVM. I use this TPM library: [link](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tss) and I run the write/read example. When I run it as Admin I can write and read successfully, when I run the same example as user it fails, even after setting these registry values. What else can prevent the user account from accessing this TPM feature? or any TPM feature?

Comment: OK so I'm assuming that you then also have an entry for `TPM2_CC_NV_Write` (with hex code 137). Also, note that for the user account, you're supposed to use the `AllowedW8UserCommands` registry key (the `AllowedW8Commands` key in my answer is for the admin account, I just caught that at the bottom of that article) so try that...

Comment: So I tried that as well and the app still couldn't get access as user.
I debuged the app and saw that an error returned from unmarshaling in Tss2_Sys_ExecuteFinish <- Esys_hierarchyChangeAuth_Finish.
I checked again and I added "129" command code (hierarchyChangeAuth) to the list of AllowedW8UserCommands

Comment: There's something else we're missing, some other windows configuration probably

Comment: Hmm don't understand why HierarchyChangeAuth is involved, if all you're trying to do is read some memory. Hard to help troubleshoot any further without the code... Good luck!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213621/discussion-between-alex-and-mnistic).